# How do I murder a ghost? / How do I unlock werewolf character?

Tags: streets-of-rogue

Apparently, to unlock werewolf, I need to murder a ghost.

I tried to hit them but failed to damage them. They don't seem to be affected by guns either. How do I murder them?

[image: Werewolf screen]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the gun "Ghost Gibber", which is in the starting loadout of Scientist.

[image: Scientist Starter Items]

So just try playing as scientist, and when you stumble upon a Ghost, just use "Ghost Gibber" to murder it. After you do that, you'll unlock Werewolf.

[image: Werewolf Unlock]